# loading screen not centered on second launch

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a `UIView` which is my loading view.  All it does is display the circular loading circle(lol to much "circle" for one sentence).
It works fine the first time but after that the circle is not centered.  It moves to the left and down some.  How can I get it to always be centered, take in mind I have limited the app to only display in the landscape modes (landscape left, landscape right) in all views so the issue is not coming from the device being rotated.

call to load the view:

```
loadingViewController = [LoadingViewController loadSpinnerIntoView:self.view];
```

LoadingViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "CrestronClient.h"
@interface LoadingViewController : UIView
{
    CrestronClient *cClient;


}
+(LoadingViewController *)loadSpinnerIntoView:(UIView *)superView;
-(void)removeLoadingView;
- (UIImage *)addBackground;
@end
```

LoadingView.m:

```
    #import "LoadingViewController.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"
@implementation LoadingViewController

CGRect priorFrameSettings;
UIView *parentView;


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ) {
        return YES;
    }else{
        return NO;
    }

}


-(void)removeLoadingView
{

//    [parentView setFrame:priorFrameSettings];

    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];

    [animation setType:kCATransitionFade];

    [[[self superview] layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"layerAnimation"];

    [self removeFromSuperview];
}

+(LoadingViewController *)loadSpinnerIntoView:(UIView *)superView
{

    priorFrameSettings = superView.frame;
    parentView = superView;
   // [superView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 1024)];


    // Create a new view with the same frame size as the superView


LoadingViewController *loadingViewController = [[LoadingViewController alloc] initWithFrame:superView.frame];

loadingViewController.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    // If something's gone wrong, abort!

    if(!loadingViewController){ return nil; }


    [superView addSubview:loadingViewController];

    if(!loadingViewController){ return nil; }

    // This is the new stuff here ;)

    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator =

    [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]

      initWithActivityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge] autorelease];

    // Set the resizing mask so it's not stretched
    UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[loadingViewController addBackground]];

    // Make a little bit of the superView show through

    background.alpha = 0.7;

    [loadingViewController addSubview:background];

    indicator.autoresizingMask =

    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |

    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |

    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |

    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;

    // Place it in the middle of the view

    indicator.center =   superView.center;

    // Add it into the spinnerView

    [loadingViewController addSubview:indicator];

    // Start it spinning! Don't miss this step

    [indicator startAnimating];


    // Create a new animation

    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];

    // Set the type to a nice wee fade

    [animation setType:kCATransitionFade];

    // Add it to the superView

    [[superView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"layerAnimation"];


    return loadingViewController;

}
- (UIImage *)addBackground{

    cClient = [CrestronClient sharedManager];
    if (cClient.isConnected == FALSE) {
        [cClient connect];
    }
    // Create an image context (think of this as a canvas for our masterpiece) the same size as the view

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, YES, 1);

    // Our gradient only has two locations - start and finish. More complex gradients might have more colours

    size_t num_locations = 2;

    // The location of the colors is at the start and end

    CGFloat locations[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };

    // These are the colors! That's two RBGA values

    CGFloat components[8] = {

        0.4,0.4,0.4, 0.8,

        0.1,0.1,0.1, 0.5 };

    // Create a color space

    CGColorSpaceRef myColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // Create a gradient with the values we've set up

    CGGradientRef myGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (myColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);

    // Set the radius to a nice size, 80% of the width. You can adjust this

    float myRadius = (self.bounds.size.width*.8)/2;

    // Now we draw the gradient into the context. Think painting onto the canvas

    CGContextDrawRadialGradient (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), myGradient, self.center, 0, self.center, myRadius, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);

    // Rip the 'canvas' into a UIImage object

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // And release memory

    CGColorSpaceRelease(myColorspace);

    CGGradientRelease(myGradient);

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // … obvious.

    return image;

}
- (void)dealloc {

    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: It's not relevant to your activity view being off-center, but UIView subclasses aren't sent rotation and loading messages (e.g., `-viewDidLoad`, `-shouldAutorotate...`, etc.).

Comment: i noticed this from the warnings, but the viewdidload does get called and im using it so i figured i would leave it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed the background by adding

```
[background setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768 )];
```

and fixed the centering of the circle with:

```
indicator.center =   background.center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the loading view is set to its parents frame and has the proper `autoresizingMask` set. This would likely by `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`.

Comment: on setting the frame to the parent i have the same issue where it works first time now on the second run though the see through background leaves out a quarter of the screen on the right.  Im not sure how to do the auto resizing stuff especially since i already apply the resizing mask.  is there something wrong with the way im doing the mask?

Comment: You are setting the `autoresizingMask` of the `indicator` in your example but not `loadingViewController`. Try setting `loadingViewController `.

Comment: try loadingViewController.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

Comment: Also, why class name is LoadingViewController? And remove next methods: - (void)viewDidLoad; - (void)viewDidUnload;
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;

Comment: @Joe ya i noticed that fact and tried to set the mask on the uiview (LoadingViewController)but the outcome is the same.

Comment: i have removed viewdidload and viewdidunload and added     loadingViewController.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
 but it still is not full screen after the first time its loaded